# PHP create combinations in array

Tags: php, arrays, implode

Let's say I have an array containing: `apples, watermelons, grapes`. What I'm trying to do is create another array with

`apples, apples;watermelons, apples;watermelons;grapes`

I tried using implode, but it's not exactly what I wanted. Is there a built in function for this task? Thanks!

EDIT: For clarification, the created string is basically a combination of these three elements. So the created array could also look like:

`apples, apples-watermelons, apples-watermelons-grapes`

Comment: it will be an array containing a string similar to that. it could be apples, apples-watermelons, apples-watermelons-grapes

Comment: Can you clarify what you are trying to do? Are you trying to make strings with random values picked from that array? Maybe you could provide a concrete example.

Comment: It is a concrete example, everything is picked in order :|

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An elegant way to do it is with [array_reduce](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

```
<?php
$my_array = array('apples','watermelons','grapes');

function collapse($result, $item) {
    $result[] = end($result) !== FALSE ? end($result) . ';' . $item : $item;
    return $result;
}

$collapsed = array_reduce($my_array, "collapse", array());
var_dump($collapsed);
?>
```

Testing:

```
matt@wraith:~/Dropbox/Public/StackOverflow$ php 11876147.php 
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "apples"
  [1]=>
  string(18) "apples;watermelons"
  [2]=>
  string(25) "apples;watermelons;grapes"
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<?php
$my_array = array('apples','watermelons','grapes');
$string = '';
$result = array();
for ($i=0; $i<count($my_array); $i++) {
   $string .= $my_array[$i];
   $result[] = $string;
   $string .= '-';
}
print_r($result);
```

There may be a way to do it with `array_walk()` or `array_map()` or one of the other `array_*()` functions as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$array = array("apples", "watermelons", "grapes");
$newarray = $array;
for ($i = 1; $i < count($array); $i++)
{
   $newarray[$i] = $newarray[$i - 1] . ";" . $newarray[$i] ;
}

print_r($newarray);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [0] => apples
    [1] => apples;watermelons
    [2] => apples;watermelons;grapes
)
```